# Python class instantiation with constraint

Tags: python, class

Say I would like to create a python class called `Vector` (this is only a toy example).
I would write the following:

```py
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, dimension, coordinates):
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.coordinates = coordinates

vec = Vector(3, [10, 20, 30])
```

Now say I write `vec = Vector(3,[10, 20, 30, 40])`, what I would like is an error of the form `"invalid vector dimension"`.

In other words, first parameter should be equal to the length of the second parameter.

I realize it does not make a lot of sense here but again, it is just a toy example.

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried in terms of having an error?

Comment: `if dimension != len(coordinates): raise ValueError("invalid vector dimension")` (why pass it in and not just calculate it using `len(coordinates)` anyways?)

Comment: Add logic inside the `__init__()` function to check the dimensions, and raise an exception if they're wrong.

Comment: previous remark gives you a way to do, and yes is a toy (or sadistic :-) ), because to ask the caller to give both dimension and coordinates is just a way to help him to make a mistake, only coordinates is useful because dimension can be deduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
class Vector:
    def __init__(self, dimension, coordinates):
        if len(coordinates) != dimension: raise ValueError("Coordinates doesn't match dimension")
        self.dimension = dimension
        self.coordinates = coordinates
```

In case you don't look at comments, @JeffUK noted:

> Doing this as a one-liner has the benefit of showing the check in the traceback

Comment: NB: Doing this as a one-liner has the benefit of showing the check in the traceback

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am new to python, "Doing this as a one-liner has the benefit of showing the check in the traceback" is mysterious to me, could you please be more explicit?

Comment: Okay, I will try to show something from traceback

Comment: @DeepNet When an error is raised, the traceback message shows the line that caused the error.  So if you have the `if` and the `raise` on the same line, that line will be shown in the error traceback, and you can very easily see the failed condition that caused the error.  However, the error message in the `raise` statement already says everything you would want to know, so this trick isn't terribly useful in this case.